# How to use a private key with windows openssh

Tags: windows, ssh, cmd

I was wondering if it was possible when using `openssh` from the Windows
command prompt if I would be able to make it use a private key instead of asking
me to enter a password?

Here is what it gives me. (No option to set or use a private key)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CI5z.png

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer an alternative ssh client **plink.exe** from Putty package available at http://www.putty.org/

```
plink.exe -ssh -i YourPrivateKey.ppk root@whatever.net
```